# Efficient way to determine the outcome of test matrix

Tags: php, validation, matrix, implementation

Related Questions:

- [Matrix Combination Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531987/matrix-combination-logic)
- [Would cartesian product be the best approach for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282688/would-cartesian-product-be-the-best-approach-for-this)

I have 25 validations, each validation returns a boolean ( true it passed, false it failed ).

Each validation can be combined with all other validations to form a Matrix of validation test  combinations.

Specific combinations of the sub-set validations will also have pass/fail rules.

Here is a short example:

```
    V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5
M1:  T |  T |  T |  T |  T   <-- For this Matrix row it would PASS
M2:  F |  T |  T |  F |  T   <-- For this Matrix row it would FAIL  
M3:  F |  F |  T |  T |  T   <-- For this Matrix row it would PASS
M4:  T |  F |  F |  F |  F   <-- For this Matrix row it would PASS
M5:  T |  T |  F |  F |  F   <-- For this Matrix row it would FAIL
```

I only care about the horizontal validation tests the vertical are for values

I know all the tests and store the outcome of each test in a database.
I know all the combination Matrix for the sub-set of all the validation test.

My question is:

What would be the best way to run the Matrix?

Do I store each permutation of each passing or failing test for the Matrix validation?
And then where do I store the Matrix combinations?

I'm thinking the only way to do this is to store all the validations combinations for the 25 tests ( yeah 625 entries ) and add the Matrix results I'm expecting for those validations in the same record.

Some something like this

```
    V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 | V5 | MR ( Matrix Results )
M1:  T |  T |  T |  T |  T | P   <-- For this Matrix row it would PASS
M2:  F |  T |  T |  F |  T | F   <-- For this Matrix row it would FAIL  
M3:  F |  F |  T |  T |  T | P   <-- For this Matrix row it would PASS
M4:  T |  F |  F |  F |  F | P   <-- For this Matrix row it would PASS
M5:  T |  T |  F |  F |  F | F   <-- For this Matrix row it would FAIL
```

I just feel like there might be a more optimal solution that I'm not seeing, any thoughts?

Comment: can you clarify what you are looking for in an answer? What do you mean by "how do I run the matrix?"

Comment: @Gordon yes runs the Matrix and Store the Matrix combinations, Looking for the best solution for both. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I would do it.  First define your matrix map in an array:

```
$map = array( 'TTTTT' => TRUE, 'FTTFT' => FALSE, 'FFTTT' => TRUE );
```

Obviously there will be more elements in that array, but you get the point.  I don't know your table/column names, but next CONCAT v1-v5 and pull as a string.  Then, just find that key in the map array:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) AS matrix FROM `validation` WHERE `user`= '$user'";
$result = $mysqli->query( $sql );
$user_matrix = array();
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) $user_matrix[] = $map[ $row['matrix'] ];
```

Now you have the results in the $user_matrix array

Comment: +1 I like the idea of CONCAT, this is something I will look into. Thanks!

Comment: Using `CONCAT` in one query and `array_to_string(array_agg(field),'')` in another I get the matrix I need. Thanks