# Would cartesian product be the best approach for this

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, matrix, cartesian-product

Related Questions:

- [Matrix Combination Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531987/matrix-combination-logic)
- [Efficient way to determine the outcome of test matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139723/efficient-way-to-determine-the-outcome-of-test-matrix)

I have 25 individual validations that I need to test all possible combinations, I have seen a couple of questions related to what I'm looking for. The answers suggested something along the lines of using the cartesian product. Would that be the best method for finding the results I'm looking for or is there a better way?

Example:

Think about a 9 by 9 number grid starting from 0 - 9 on the X and Y axis:

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
|1|
|2|
|3|
|4|
|5|
|6|
|7|
|8|
|9|
```

All the individual validations are boolean ( true = passed, false = failed ).

The X Axis represents all the test results, Example:

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
|1|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|2|
|3|
|4|
|5|
|6|
|7|
|8|
|9|
```

And the Y Axis represents all the possible combinations, Example:

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
|1|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|2|F|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|3|F|F|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|4|F|F|F|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|5|F|F|F|F|T|T|T|T|T|
|6|F|F|F|F|F|T|T|T|T|
|7|F|F|F|F|F|F|T|T|T|
|8|F|F|F|F|F|F|F|T|T|
|9|F|F|F|F|F|F|F|F|T|
```

There will be more Y Axis combinations but I hope you get the point.

My question is how would I go about solving all the possible combinations?

Comment: I think this more of a math question than a programming question, is it not? Maybe you will have more luck at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My suggestion, You have to check the result in reverse order, that means you  should check combination [9,9], if it fails check [8,8] if [8,8] gives true then check [8,9].... I think you got the point.

Comment: For clarity about my suggestion, check reverse diagonally until you get you get a true, then go left to right, this might reduce the overall process time.