# Matrix Combination Logic

Tags: php, matrix, logic

**NOTE: **Please read all other related questions**:**

Here is my first and second attempts at asking this question:

- [Efficient way to determine the outcome of test matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139723/efficient-way-to-determine-the-outcome-of-test-matrix)
- [Would cartesian product be the best approach for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282688/would-cartesian-product-be-the-best-approach-for-this)

Here is the problem:

- I have several ( like 20 ) Boolean validations ( true / false )
- All Boolean validations as a whole also have a validation Result

I'm trying to find the best solution to test all the validations and also the validation result. I was looking into a Matrix to hold all possible combinations but that might be an overkill.

Here is an example ( 1 - 20 ):

- test_1 = Has 30 Kills
- test_2 = Has Found Map 1
- test_3 = Has Mastered Level 1
- test_4 = Has Achieved Grunt Status
- test_5 = Has Assault weapon
- test_6 = Has Knife
- test_7 = Has Grenade
- test_x = Etc...

So when the Player has all these validations as TRUE I can then give a level result

- if test_1, test_2, test_3 ( any combination of the three ): level = green

All combinations are ( 15 ):

- test_1
- test_2
- test_3
- test_1, test_2
- test_1, test_3
- test_2, test_1 ( duplicate can skip this )
- test_2, test_3
- test_3, test_1 ( duplicate can skip this )
- test_3, test_2 ( duplicate can skip this )
- test_1, test_2, test_3
- test_1, test_3, test_2 ( duplicate can skip this )
- test_2, test_1, test_3 ( duplicate can skip this )
- test_2, test_3, test_1 ( duplicate can skip this )
- test_3, test_1, test_2 ( duplicate can skip this )
- test_3, test_2, test_1 ( duplicate can skip this )

So unique combinations are ( 7 instead of 15 ):

- test_1
- test_2
- test_3
- test_1, test_2
- test_1, test_3
- test_2, test_3
- test_1, test_2, test_3

Now I'm trying to find the best possible solution to find unique combinations for all 20 validations and come up with a level validation from that matrix.

UPDATE:

Also I need to find only TRUE Combinations so you might read the Unique Combinations like this:

- test_1
- test_2
- test_3
- test_1, test_2
- test_1, test_3
- test_2, test_3
- test_1, test_2, test_3

Boolean Value Results from Validation Tests

- TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
- FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
- FALSE, FALSE, TRUE
- TRUE, TRUE, FALSE
- TRUE, FALSE, TRUE
- FALSE, TRUE, TRUE
- TRUE, TRUE, TRUE

So any of these combinations would be a GREEN level.

Also I need to know the order of the test validations as well as the matrix order to compare for level assignment. So for GREEN level I only need the validation result combination matrix for test 1, 2 and 3. So I could ignore tests 4 - 20

UPDATE #2:

I know this looks like a simple OR condition but I wanted to take out the combination logic to set the level into a matrix. I could use the matrix of combinations to determine the level logic without having to code additional or modify current logic in the code itself. I wanted to just compare the validations results for a given set of tests and assign a level to those results. Different permutations of the validation combinations would result in different level assignments.

I understand that I could add the combination logic in the code itself, but as this logic looks to be very volatile and thought this might offer a more flexible solution.
Suggestions?

Comment: 20 boolean variables fit inside a single 32-bit integer. If you store them like that, you can do very fast parallel checks.

Comment: Maybe a good starting point: http://www.sonyjose.in/blog/?p=62

Comment: What you need is a partition set generator.

Comment: @iccthedral could you explain a little more?

Comment: if any one of tests 1,2,3 need to indicate level green you can go for `if($test_1 || $test_2 || $test_3)` and skip checking of status using these three

Comment: @Gordon as you where on another related question, any suggestions?

Comment: @MohamedNavas I understand how to do a if condition and the question I posted simplifies the problem I'm facing. As new combinations arise I wanted to add this level logic in a matrix so I could bypass having to add any additional code logic. For example if I wanted to change/add/remove a combination I could do it from the validation combinations that will assign the level instead of adding that logic itself. I hope that I'm explaining this correctly

Comment: If any of the combination would be Green then none would be RED unless because only an empty array would not any combination ?

Comment: empty or all false results is a white default level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(removed my two previous answers for clarity)

After your last edit, instead of answering directly, I would like first to be sure to 100% understand the "**level detection algorithm**" you want.

If I understand well, you would like to define/maintain a simple configuration structure telling which tests give which level.

e.g. with an associative array:

```
array(
  'green' => array('test1', 'test2', 'test3'),
  'orange' => array('test2', 'test3', 'test5')
  ...
  );
```

With the meaning: if one or more of the tests in the list are satisfied, assign that level (array key) to the player. Such logic could easily cover quite a lot of combinations, and would avoid handling a huge matrix.

Maybe you want to extend the logic to tell, for example, that at least N tests among the test list are satisfied.

```
array(
  'green' => array(
      'tests' => array('test1', 'test2', 'test3'),
      'nb_required' => 2
    ),
  ...
  );
```

Is that what you want?

BTW, why don't you use a classic XP/level up system? :-p

Comment: +1 for the effort - This is close to what I need but if I add all twenty validations it's going to be too much: array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U");

Comment: It looks like the `$combinationarray` becomes huge. The `$combocount` is greater than **two million** elements for 20 validations. Supposing that we succeed to get all combinations, how do you will assign a level to each combination?

Comment: That is what this effort is trying to do but I can't see assigning two million records to a level. I know what combinations a level would assign.

Comment: Maybe I need to find all combinations for each level instead of all 20 validations. So out of twenty validations if tests 1, 2, 3 and 5 are true, assign level green. Thoughts?...

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. Stepping back and looking at your solution seems to simplify my needs instead of using a matrix which looks to be more complicated for all the combinations. Will test this and keep you posted. A big thanks as this is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction**

You can easy get combinations like this :

```
echo "<pre>";
$test = ["test_1","test_2","test_3"];

// Get Combination
$return = uniqueCombination($test);

//Sort
sort($return);

//Pretty Print
print_r(array_map(function($v){ return implode(",", $v); }, $return));

function uniqueCombination($in, $minLength = 1, $max = 10) {
    $count = count($in);
    $members = pow(2, $count);
    $return = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $members; $i ++) {
        $b = sprintf("%0" . $count . "b", $i);
        $out = array();
        for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j ++)
            $b{$j} == '1' and $out[] = $in[$j];

        count($out) >= $minLength && count($out) <= $max and $return[] = $out;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => test_1
    [1] => test_2
    [2] => test_3
    [3] => test_1,test_2
    [4] => test_1,test_3
    [5] => test_2,test_3
    [6] => test_1,test_2,test_3
)
```

**The Problem**

They are about `1,048,576` combination and i believe this is not the kind of array you want i would suggest a condition based combination rather than all possible combination

Example

```
// Game Conditions
$game = new Game();
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(1), new Kill(30)));
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(2), new Map(1), new Kill(10)));
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(3), new Grunt(10)));
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(4), new Knife(1), new Ak47(1)));
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(5), new Grenade(1), new Combo(7)));
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(6), new Kill(100), new Blow(10), new Stab(10)));
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(7), new Herb(10), new Medipack(1), new Map(1), new Artwork(1)));
$game->addCondition(new Condition(new Level(8), new Grenade(20),new Artwork(5)));


// User Starts Game
$user = new User($game);


$user->task(new Map(1));
$user->task(new Herb(5));
$user->task(new Kill(10));
$user->task(new Kill(10));
$user->task(new Herb(10));
$user->task(new Kill(10));
$user->task(new Kill(10));
$user->task(new Ak47(1));
$user->task(new Knife(1));
$user->task(new Map(1));
$user->task(new Grunt(17));
$user->task(new Kill(60));
$user->task(new Combo(1));
$user->task(new Kill(40));
$user->task(new Medipack(1));
$user->task(new Artwork(1));
$user->task(new Grenade(1));
$user->task(new Combo(10));
$user->task(new Blow(10));
$user->task(new Stab(5));
$user->task(new Blow(10));
$user->task(new Stab(5));
$user->task(new Stab(5));

printf("\n<b>Total Point %s",number_format($user->getPoint(),0));
```

Output

```
+Task Map   Added  (1)
+Task Herb  Added  (5)
+Task Kill  Added  (10)
^Task Kill  Updated (20)
^Task Herb  Updated (15)
^Task Kill  Updated (30)

*Level 1 Completed* 


*Level 2 Completed* 

^Task Kill  Updated (40)
+Task Ak47  Added  (1)
+Task Knife     Added  (1)
^Task Map   Updated (2)
+Task Grunt     Added  (17)

*Level 3 Completed* 


*Level 4 Completed* 

^Task Kill  Updated (100)
+Task Combo     Added  (1)
^Task Kill  Updated (140)
+Task Medipack  Added  (1)
+Task Artwork   Added  (1)
+Task Grenade   Added  (1)
^Task Combo     Updated (11)

*Level 5 Completed* 

+Task Blow  Added  (10)
+Task Stab  Added  (5)
^Task Blow  Updated (20)
^Task Stab  Updated (10)

*Level 6 Completed* 


*Level 7 Completed* 

^Task Stab  Updated (15)


<b>Total Point 1,280</b>
```

Classes Used

```
class Task {
    private $no;

    function __construct($no = 1) {
        $this->no = $no;
    }

    function getNo() {
        return $this->no;
    }

    function getName() {
        return get_called_class();
    }

    function merge(Task $task) {
        $this->no += $task->getNo();
        return $this;
    }
}
class User {
    private $game;
    private $point;
    private $tasks = array();

    function __construct(Game $game) {
        $this->game = $game;
    }

    function getPoint() {
        return $this->point;
    }

    function getTask() {
        return $this->tasks;
    }

    function task(Task $task) {
        if (isset($this->tasks[$task->getName()])) {
            $this->tasks[$task->getName()]->merge($task);
            printf("^Task %s \tUpdated (%s)\n", $this->tasks[$task->getName()]->getName(), $this->tasks[$task->getName()]->getNo());
        } else {
            printf("+Task %s \tAdded  (%s)\n", $task->getName(), $task->getNo());
            $this->tasks[$task->getName()] = $task;
        }

        $this->point += $task->getNo() * $task->d;
        $this->game->notify($this);
    }
}
class Condition {
    private $task = array();
    private $status = false;

    function __construct(Level $level) {
        $this->level = $level;
        $tasks = func_get_args();
        array_shift($tasks);
        $this->task = new SplObjectStorage($tasks);
        foreach ( $tasks as $task )
            $this->task->attach($task);
    }

    function update(Game $game, User $user) {
        if ($this->status)
            return;
        $n = 0;
        foreach ( $this->task as $cTask ) {
            foreach ( $user->getTask() as $task ) {
                if ($cTask->getName() == $task->getName()) {
                    if ($task->getNo() >= $cTask->getNo())
                        $n ++;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($n === count($this->task) && ($game->getLevel()->getNo() + 1) == $this->level->getNo()) {
            $this->status = true;
            $game->setLevel($this->level);
            printf("\n*Level %d Completed* \n\n", $this->level->getNo());
        }
    }

    function getStatus() {
        return $this->status;
    }
}
class Game {
    private $taskCondition;
    private $level;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->taskCondition = new SplObjectStorage();
        $this->level = new Level(0);
    }

    function setLevel(Level $level) {
        $this->level = $level;
    }

    function getLevel() {
        return $this->level;
    }

    function addCondition($condition) {
        $this->taskCondition->attach($condition);
    }

    public function notify($user) {
        foreach ( $this->taskCondition as $conditions ) {
            if ($conditions->getStatus() === true) {
                // detached completed condition
                $this->taskCondition->detach($conditions);
                continue;
            }
            $conditions->update($this, $user);
        }
    }

    public function hasCondition() {
        return count($this->taskCondition);
    }
}

class Level extends Task{}
class Action extends Task{};
class Weporn extends Task{};
class Skill extends Task{};
class Tresure extends Task{};
class Medicine extends Task{};

class Kill extends Action{public $d = 5 ;};
class Blow extends Action{public $d = 7 ;};
class Stab extends Action{public $d = 10 ;};

class Map extends Tresure{public $d = 10 ;};
class Artwork extends Tresure{public $d = 20 ;};

class Knife extends Weporn{public $d = 5 ;};
class Grenade extends Weporn{public $d = 10 ;};
class Ak47 extends Weporn{public $d = 10 ;};

class Jump extends Skill{public $d = 2 ;};
class Grunt  extends Skill{public $d = 4 ;};
class Combo extends Skill{public $d = 7 ;};

class Medipack extends Medicine{public $d = 5 ;};
class Herb extends Medicine{public $d = 5 ;};
```

[Simple Online Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xKsEX8)

Comment: +1 for the effort - This is close to what I need but if I add all twenty validations it's going to be too much: array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U");

Comment: Maybe I need to find all combinations for each level instead of all 20 validations. So out of twenty validations if tests 1, 2, 3 and 5 are true, assign level green. Thoughts?...

Comment: This is a very difficult one ... because they are `67,108,864` possible unique combinations .... you can not save that to memory ...

Comment: Yeah and I think I'm over complicating it. Basically what I need is a way to setup different combinations of validations and a corresponding level(s).

Comment: Thanks Baba, I really do appreciate the effort but I think FrostyZ's solution is what I have been searching for. I had to step back and look at what I really needed to implement the simplest solution. +1 for the efforts and thanks

Comment: Its the same thing i did but instead of just using string i defined `new Condition`  for each `new Level` Can you see that as the user progress the level is automatically updated with out having to look at all possible combination .. the main issue with is solution is that its good for example but in real word `'tests' => array('test1', 'test2', 'test3')` can not just be strings ...

Comment: I see your point but in this case I like the solution of being able to add an array of validation results instead of a new condition

Answer (score 1):

Not quite to answer your question, but it seems you're missing something.

Lets say you have twenty tests, labeled 1 though *n*.  Decide for test *n* whether you want to validate for it, or not.   Either you include the test for validation, or you don't. That's two choices for every test. Proceed through (*n*-1) until you have no more tests.    For *n*=20, that's 2^20 = 1048576 possible combinations of tests (including one combination where you don't select any tests), which means 1048576 results. Now I still don't understand what you mean by "level of validation", but I have to wonder why you'd need that many combinations of tests in the first place.

Edit:  Well, a test matrix  (so to speak) could work.... but you'd still have to generate the matrix.  You're likely not going to hand code all 1048576 combinations.  But supposing you've already created the mapping, you just have a zero indexed array as a look up table with 1048576 values that you desire and you're done!  All you would need to map the test results to the matrix would be assigning each test a binary digit (test1 would be the one's place, test2 would be the 2's place, etc.)

What I suspect you really want is a quick way to generate the *mapping* given some broader rules you might encode in php... but here's funny part about that.  If you had some code that generated the matrix for any and every set of tests, the matrix is then superfluous;  Your code is essentially a *compressed representation* for the matrix.  The only point in using one over the other is whether or not one would be faster than the other.

It also seems you really don't care about all 1048576 combinations.  I suspect it might benefit you to partition your tests into their own set of tests  (one for red, one for blue, etc). For instance, if you partition tests into groups of 5,  and there is, oh, 3 different possibilities (instead of 16) for each group, you're only working with  (3 different results per group)^(4 groups) = 81 unique results.  Eighty one unique results is much more manageable than over a million.

It seems you may also need different partitions for different independent things. It also may not matter even which tests result in true as long as *a certain number of them are true*, that is "goal: 3 out of 5 blue objectives met"  "goal: 7 out of 10 red and blue objectives met" or whatever.  Those tests would have to be accessed independently and they wouldn't necessarily be multiplicative with the results of the other tests-- there will never be 7 out of 10 red and blue objectives met if none of your blue objectives are met (I'll admit, this is hard to explain further without an example).

So, really, there's no quick answer.  Either you deal with all and every one of the 1048576  combinations **individually**, or you create *and encode* some sort of generic grouping scheme for your tests to drastically cut down on combinations.  You can certainly create your full matrix scheme by said scheme, and maybe even dynamically generate your full 1048576  element matrix for a given set of combinations. But you cannot burn a whole candle by only burning half of it.

Edit II (and III):

I'm going to make one more guess.  The levels you've proposed seem to be related to the number of objectives completed per each (and previous batch).  So encode your results in to a string of ("T", and "F") and count the "F"s for each batch and determine from there.  If the count of Fs is the number of characters in the string, no objective of the batch is completed, if the number of Fs is zero, all objectives of the batch are completed.

Lets say the batch after blue is purple.  Could somebody achieve a goal in purple without completing all the green batch? If so, you have another color to assign for that possibility; if not, then, I would assume that these levels are ordered (orange between green and blue, maybe "brown" or something between blue and purple--you can tell I pulled this out of thin air-- and it should be fairly simple to cascade through these counts to determine the current "level".

If there is no ordering, then it's quite analogous to the situation I mentioned above:  Each group has a result { "no objectives completed", "some objectives completed", "all objectives completed"}.  There are `x` groups which means `3^x` possible results. You should be basing your level matrix on *these* results, not the results of the tests previously mentioned.

Comment: I do need to validate if all test are FALSE but I have a subset of TRUE validations for each level assignment. Like tests 1,2,3,4 combinations are assigned to level green, 5,6,7,8,9,10 are level blue and so on. BUt now I have the dilema of now if tests 1,2,3 and 5 are true this should be level orange. Looking for a easy way to set a combination of test results to a level without the need to code for every new combination that is added. so If I have all green level combinations in a matrix I could just query my results against those combinations but from a matrix of all combinations

Comment: so levels red, blue, green, orange, etc.. are all in the combination matrix. Taking the test validation results I could compare and get the assigned level

Comment: Thanks! this did help me out. I think FrostyZ's solution is what I've been looking for +1 for the effort

Answer (score 0):

I  have found the graphic display of your question as you mentioned.

```
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
|1|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|2|F|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|3|F|F|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|4|F|F|F|T|T|T|T|T|T|
|5|F|F|F|F|T|T|T|T|T|
|6|F|F|F|F|F|T|T|T|T|
|7|F|F|F|F|F|F|T|T|T|=>[7,9] if this is the answer
|8|F|F|F|F|F|F|F|T|T|
|9|F|F|F|F|F|F|F|F|T|
```

In my opinion you should check the conditions in reverse diagonal order, then left to right.
That means

first check [9,9]

if it fails check [8,8]

if this fails check [7,7]

if it  gives true check [7,8]

if this gives false check [7,9] this must be the answer and the simple shortcut,

This method will reduce over all process time.

Comment: Thanks, it's not just the one answer in the matrix I'm looking for. I need the whole set to assign a level to it

Comment: I thought you are going for TRUE answers only, and you wish to find the final true answer...? am I correct.

Comment: I updated my question but I need to find a set of TRUE validations to assign a level

Comment: [7,1],[7,2]... upto [7,6] are false, then why should you go for it.   Also if you are saying [7,1] is equivalent to [1,7] then you done a mistake at representation of matrix. You have to represent it in TRUE status at cells of [1,1](top left) to [1,9](top right) and, [1,1](top left) to [9,1](bottom left). ie, Fill TRUE in triangle region inside top left - top right - bottom left.

Comment: sorry that matrix is an example and does not show all permutations that are possible. Example: what if [7,1] and [7,9] are TRUE

Comment: is [7,1] equivalent to [1,7]?

Comment: Sorry that I'm sticking on the matrix, I think you may asking what if [7,1] and [7,9] are true and [7,7] is false, am I correct?